# How to apply multiple css transform properties using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to apply some dynamic ***scale*** and ***translate*** css properties some thing like this

```
var scale="scale(2,2)";
var translate="translate(20,20)";
var prop=scale+" "+translate;
$(this).css({
            "transform":prop
             });
```

But this is not working. I even tried some thing like this

```
 prop="'"+scale+" "+translate+"'";
$(this).css({"transform":prop});
```

Even this not working.Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Give units for the `translate` transform. It won't work without it. Otherwise, nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Harry, you **have** to have measurement units on your `translate` property.

See below:

```
var scale="scale(2,2)";
var translate="translate(20px,20px)";
var prop=scale+" "+translate;
$(this).css({
   "transform":prop
});
```

A slightly easier alternative is to do a class change instead, and assign your `transform` styling to the new class.

Like this:

```
$(this).addClass('transform-me');
```

And the CSS

```
.transform-me {
  transform:translate(20px, 20px) scale(2,2);
}
```

Doing it this way achieves the exact same results, but it does simplify troubleshooting where the error is occurring (whether it is the CSS or the jQuery causing problems).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another way using css matrix and manipulating it with jquery. Powerful way to adjust images. In the following example, we setup variables to hold the data and move an image left by 1 pixel.

```
var prior = parseInt($(this).css('transform').split(',')[4]) || 0;
lastX -= 1;
args = [lastScale, 0, 0, lastScale, lastX, lastY]
$(this).css('transform', 'matrix(' + args.join(",") + ')');
```